# How to get data associated with branch.io deeplinks in the desktop redirected website?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I am generating a branch.io deeplink in my react native app using the below code

```
let branchUniversalObject = await branch.createBranchUniversalObject(
    canonicalIdentifier,
    {
      locallyIndex: true,
      title,
      contentImageUrl,
      contentDescription: contentDescription || '',
      contentMetadata: {
        customMetadata,
      },
    }
  )
```

It gives me a link something like https://xyz.abc.com/OrzOISGRP0

I have kept my localhost for desktop url in branch.io settings.

Now my question is, is there a way i can get the customMetadata associated with this deeplink in the website?

I tried using branch.init() web sdk, but its not returning the required data if i open the link directly, it redirects me though and also appends branch_match_id.

It sends the data in listener registered on site if someone have clicked the link and opened it on phone, i dont know whats the use of that.

Thanks

Comment: So just to be clear here with the requirements, you are trying to get the link data (customMetadata) in the redirected Website? If this is true, take a look at this stack overflow answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42586219/4348158

Comment: @AniV Thanks. So, I can use query parameters. But is there a way i can get the data just by branch.io's generated link?